# IIf error in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 columns in MS Access. Not all rows are filled.
What I want to achieve is:

- If the value in column A is bigger than column B, then I want "1" in
  column C.
- If the value in column A is smaller than the value in column B, then I
  want "0" in column C.
- If there is no value in column A, then I want "-" in column C.

I've been trying everything but can't seem to figure it out.
This is what I've been trying:

```
IIf([W3]>[L3];"1";IIf(IsEmpty([W3]);"0";"-"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIf(IsNull([W3];"-";IIf([W3]>[L3];"1";"0"))
```

or:

```
=IIf([W3] Is Null;"-";IIf([W3]>[L3];"1";"0"))
```